# Garbage collection - what to expect?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I've got 2 `list`s, where both hold objects of same type. Let's call it `TypeX`.

When I want to add a new object of `TypeX` I'd create a new object of `TypeX` and then use `Add` to `list1` and to `list2`. Thus each list will have a reference to the actual object.
(I hope I'm right here).

Then, I'd want to remove the object. I'd use `Remove` for both `list`s. Thus the reference to the object has been removed...

But what happens to the object itself? Will the GC clean it? Should I remove it somehow else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms, the GC collects every object that is not referenced by any other object.

So, if you remove your object from both lists and don't save it anywhere else it will eventually be garbage collected.

Comment: Don't forget that if any other object registered with an event on this object, it will still be referenced!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, the GC will clean it up. However if you wish to make this more efficient I would add the interface IDisposable to your object so that the GC will dispose of the object cleanly as soon as all reference to it has gone.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Comment: `IDisposable` has nothing to do with the garbage collector.

Comment: The IDisposable interface should be implemented only if your object uses unmanaged resources(handlers,stream,etc) and it shoud care about realeasing those before the object is set to null(to allow the GC to remove it).The GC collection only removes the Object that are not anymore reachable(there are any references to it)

Comment: If you wish to improve GC collection and have resources on the object then using IDisposable will allow you to avoid finalzation queuing:

Comment: http://ashishkhandelwal.arkutil.com/index.php/csharp/how-to-improve-garbage-collection-performance/

Comment: you don't need to implement neither the dipose or the finalize method if there are not unmanaged resourced

Answer (score 0):

As long as the only references to the object are in those lists the GC will remove it after you removed it from both lists.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no more references to the object, the GC will collect the object when it finds necessary. This usually happens when the memory pressure increases or by manually giving it a 'hint' to run (you usually don't need this).

This link may be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about having a GC is that you really don't need to worry about what your're worrying now.